# Dynamically bind dropdown with months names

Tags: c#, asp.net, drop-down-menu

I place a drop downlist into my web page, then add following code to bind items to dropdown list within the page load event.

In this case is a drop downlist  with month names.

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;
using System.Globalization;
using System;
public partial class _Default : System.Web.UI.Page

{
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (!IsPostBack )
        {
            DD_Monthbind();
        }
    }

    private void DD_Monthbind()
    {
        DateTimeFormatInfo info = DateTimeFormatInfo.GetInstance(null);
        int currentMonth = DateTime.Now.Month;

        for (int i = 1; i < 13; i++)
        {
            bool isMonthInPast = i < currentMonth;

            if (!isMonthInPast)
                DropDownList1.Items.Add(new ListItem(info.GetMonthName(i), i.ToString()));
        }
    }
}
```

On this drop downlist  when the month changes, the previous month or months are no longer displayed

e.g.

with date 01 February in the list disappears the month of January.

I would need that the previous month is no longer shown after the 10th of the following month

Can you help me?

Comment: How do you want the months to be displayed? What happens to the months before and after you choose a month?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

please try below change in your code.

```
bool isMonthInPast = ((i+1) < currentMonth) || (i+1== currentMonth && DateTime.Now.Day>10);
```

Answer (score 0):

I would do something like this. Add the months from the current one and then check if the days are <= 10. If so just insert the previous month.

```
private void DD_Monthbind()
{
    DateTimeFormatInfo info = DateTimeFormatInfo.GetInstance(null);
    DateTime today = DateTime.Now;

    for (int i = today.Month; i <= 12; i++)
    {
        DropDownList1.Items.Add(new ListItem(info.GetMonthName(i), i.ToString()));
    }

    if (today.Day <= 10)
    {
        DropDownList1.Items.Insert(0, new ListItem(info.GetMonthName(today.AddMonths(-1).Month), today.AddMonths(-1).Month.ToString()));
    }
}
```

You can test various dates by changing `today`

```
DateTime today = DateTime.Now.AddMonths(5).AddDays(10);
```